# Add sequential number to new field based on a sorted ascending list (SQL in QGIS)

Tags: sql, qgis

I have a line (segmented road) dataset where each road has a unique code but that road maybe segmented. I want to add the unique code (Location) and sequential number (based on the start chainage of the segment) to a new field (segment_id).

I need it in the QGIS flavour of SQL that only allows these commands -https://sqlite.org/lang.html?

The example below has the field I want to end up with in the last (Segment_ID) column

```
fid RoadMntnc   Location    Segments    Start_Chainage  Segment_ID
640 Albatross_Cl    3   1   0   3.1
606 Allamanda_St    4   1   0   4.1
620 Barrbal_Dr  25  5   0   25.1
624 Barrbal_Dr  25  5   50  25.2
628 Barrbal_Dr  25  5   130 25.3
1092    Barrbal_Dr  25  5   180 25.4
1093    Barrbal_Dr  25  5   250 25.5
600 Bayil_Dr    27  2   120 27.2
601 Bayil_Dr    27  2   0   27.1
```

We would need to group by location and then for each group get an ascending list of the Start_Chainage and then insert 1-x to the location value to get Location.Segment#

Is this possible purely in SQL or do I need to use Python?

**==== UPDATED code example** based on QuestionGuyBob's suggestions

```
select ROW_NUMBER () OVER (
    PARTITION BY Location
    ORDER BY Start_Chainage
    ) RowNum, Location, RoadMntnc, Segments,
 CAST(Location as VARCHAR(30))+ '.'+Cast(RowNum as VARCHAR(30))  AS Segment_ID
    from test_simple_roads
```

Gives an error

```
Query preparation error on PRAGMA table_info(_tview): no such column: RowNum
```

If I change RowNum to another field it doesn't concatenate but is adding the two integers

[image]

If I change it to concat it works but I still can't use RowNum or Row_Number as i get the same error (no such column).

```
concat(Location, '.',RowNum)  AS Segment_ID
```

Comment: I'm not exactly seeing what your end result you're aiming for.  Can you provide a sample of what the output should look like?  The first idea that pops into my mind is to use something like a ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LOCATION ....

Comment: It's the last column of the table. So for fid 600 where the location is 27 we need the segment_id to be 27.2 as it starts at 120m and for 601 it should be 27.1 as it it is the first segment starting at 0m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you will want to use ROW_NUMBER() windowing function.  I looked at the documentation and it does support it.

https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html#built_in_window_functions

What you will most likely want to do is to "ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LOCATION ORDER BY FID) AS RN" in a sub-select.  Then cast the RN to a varchar and concat it to location.  Something like "CAST(Location as VARCHAR(30)) + '.' + CAST(RN AS VARCHAR(30)) AS Segment_ID

```
    SELECT
    *
    ,CAST(Location as VARCHAR(30))+ '.'+Cast(RowNum as VARCHAR(30))  AS Segment_ID
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (
    PARTITION BY Location
    ORDER BY Start_Chainage
    ) RowNum, Location, RoadMntnc, Segments
 
    from test_simple_roads) AS TEST
```

Comment: That mostly works well but it doesn't do the concatenation correctly to get the Segment_ID. I will update the Q with the code.

Comment: @GeorgeC, you need to put the entire query in a sub-select.  IE.  Select *, <insert concat here> FROM (Select ... Row_number from table.)

Comment: For reference, SQL executes via sets of data it knows.  Based on order of operations (how sql is executed) the "select" is executed near the end and, in general, as a whole.  When you want information from that select to concat, you either need to build the column within itself OR do a sub-select (wrapper).  Either sets of code will look a little more complicated, but a sub-select is easier to read, in my opinion.  I updated my answer section for you.